Does the "bracketed character" have a meaning in the titles of the episodes in Nier: Automata ver1.1a?
The title of every episode in both seasons has some capitalised letter in a bracket. For example, the first episode is called

or not to [B]e

and the second is

city e[S]cape

In the first two episodes, it can at least be inferred that [B] is for 2B and [S] is for 9S. Does the bracketed character in each title have any meaning, or is it just chosen at random?

Speaking from someone who has played the titular game and watched some of the anime, the bracketed characters do not have that much of a significant meaning by themselves. However, the name each episode does correlate to one of the 26 different endings to the titular game:
In your example, the episodes and endings are:

Ending B: or not to [B]e
Ending S: city e[S]cape

So the titles of the episodes appear to be paging homage to its original source.
